# Sign change of main variable when I add the interaction tetm

Tags: regression, interaction, pooling

I am running pooled regression for 67 group my dependent variable is gini disposable and independent variable is women empowerment (economic,social,political) and institutional quality ( government stability,democratic accountability,law & order)
When I run regression without interaction term women empowerment and institutional quality signs are negative
But when I add interaction women empowerment*institutional quality then sign of separate variable become positive and and interaction term got negative sign what it explains is it normal?

Comment: make a 3D scatterplot, with axis 1 = women's empowermnet, axis 2 = institutional quality, and axis 3 = gini disposal, to see what's going on.

Comment: See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/61506/28500) and [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/444152/28500), the other "related" pages listed on this page, and their many links. When a predictor is involved in an interaction, its coefficient represents its association with outcome when its _interacting_ coefficients are at 0 or their reference levels. You can only interpret such a single-predictor coefficient in terms of the levels of the _interacting_ predictor and the interaction coefficient(s).